# Unable to post Robot framework code and JSON file on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

When posting question, it suggest me to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. After that it suggest me to write a comment for the code, but I have already included comments on each line of the code, but it still is not allowing me to post my question.

I have included a JSON file too, but it is not formatting so I added in top line of question.
here is question

## Code 1 works, but it's partially hardcoded to get al city information. I am looking to display all key value pairs at the same time.

# Here is the JSON file:    {"class": {"id": 0,"name": "David"},"alladdress": {"count": 3,"addresslist": [{"houseno": 1,"streetno": 5,"streetname": "tesla","city": "ABC","state": "AA","country": "UK","zip": 85555},{"houseno": 2,"streetno": 6,"streetname": "honda","city": "PQR","state": "BB","country": "IN", "zip": 5252}]}}
*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Code1
    #Get JSON file
    ${json_data}=    Get file  detail.json
    #get  dictionaries under list
    ${data}=  evaluate  json.loads($json_data)  json
    ${alladdress}=  get from dictionary  ${data}  alladdress
    ${addresslist}=  get from dictionary  ${alladdress}  addresslist
    # loop over  dictionaries under list. I wanted to use loop  FOR  ${address}   in   ${addresslist.keys()} but for some reason its not working so i use this code to display key value pair
    : FOR  ${address}  in  @{addresslist}
    \   ${city} =  Get From Dictionary  ${address}   city
    \   ${key}=  set variable  ${address.keys()}
    \   ${listkey}=  get from list  ${key}  0
    # Since I know list 0 is city, but it's kind of hardcoded
    \   log to console  ${listkey}, ${city}

## I am trying to display key value pairs using the below code, but it displays error @{address.keys()}' failed: Variable '${address}' not found.

Code2
    # Get JSON file
    ${json_data}=    Get file  detail.json
    ${data}=  evaluate  json.loads($json_data)  json
    ${alladdress}=  get from dictionary  ${data}  alladdress
    ${addresslist}=  get from dictionary  ${alladdress}  addresslist
    # loop over list which contents dictionary object.
    :FOR  ${address}  IN  @{addresslist}
    \  Loop over address  @{address}
Loop over items
    [Arguments]  @{address}
    :FOR  ${key}  IN  @{address.keys()}
    \  ${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${address}    ${key}
    # Here I get error @{address.keys()}' failed: Variable '${address}' not found.
    \  log to console   ${key},${value}

Comment: You understand that you question looks, at first glance, like encrypted/encoded data, yes?

Comment: Have you looked at how others have edited your previous questions? Can you understand what they changed and why?

Comment: *but I have already included comments on each line of the code* It's not asking for comments in the code itself. It's with asking for more text explaining what your problem is or it is complaining that you haven't formatted your code properly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting You can also test using the formatting here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the "your question contains unformatted code" warning which tells you that we want your code to be formatted as code, not text.

It seems you then tried to format *your entire question as code*. This is when you would have encountered the "your question is mostly code" warning, which tells you that we want some text that *isn't* formatted as code to go with your code.

I recommend reading [The code formatting section of the editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for more information on how to properly format code blocks.

The solution is simple, we want your code to be formatted as code, and we want some text to go with your code. That's the bare minimum to get past the automatic quality filters.

Once you get past the automatic quality filters, then you need to... *actually ask a question*. I know you may think it is obvious, but you don't ask a question anywhere in your... question.

You've also structured your question in a way that makes it hard to follow. You've asked a debugging style question, so you want to include a few specific things, and exclude anything that isn't necessary. Those few specific things to include are:

- A description of the task you're trying to accomplish,
- Example input data,
- The expected output for that input data,
- The code you're using that isn't working,
- Any attempts you've made to try to solve the problem (to a degree, we don't want to sift through 15 failed attempts just to get to the question statement),
- Any errors you may have encountered (in their entirety),
- A clear problem statement (what isn't working, what is it doing that it shouldn't be, what isn't it doing that it is), and
- **A question statement**

This is my best stab at editing your question, though it could still probably use some polish. I don't know the technology so some of my noise reduction to the code may have changed the behavior, that is not my intention.

> I am trying to display a JSON file as key value pairs.
>
> Here is the JSON file:
>
> ```
> {"class": {"id": 0,"name": "David"},"alladdress": {"count": 3,"addresslist": [{"houseno": 1,"streetno": 5,"streetname": "tesla","city": "ABC","state": "AA","country": "UK","zip": 85555},{"houseno": 2,"streetno": 6,"streetname": "honda","city": "PQR","state": "BB","country": "IN", "zip": 5252}]}}
> ```
>
> Here is the common code:
>
> ```
> Library  OperatingSystem
> Library  Collections
> ${json_data}=    Get file  detail.json
> ${data}=  evaluate  json.loads($json_data)  json
> ${alladdress}=  get from dictionary  ${data}  alladdress
> ${addresslist}=  get from dictionary  ${alladdress}  addresslist
> ```
>
> In order to display the key value pairs, I wanted to use the following code to loop over the dictionaries under the list, but the code I tried below threw this error on the last line:
>
> > @{address.keys()}' failed: Variable '${address}' not found.
>
> ```
> :FOR  ${address}  IN  @{addresslist}
> \  Loop over address  @{address}
> [Arguments]  @{address}
> :FOR  ${key}  IN  @{address.keys()}
> \  ${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${address}    ${key}
> \  log to console   ${key},${value}
> ```
>
> However, this code works to display the key value pairs.
>
> ```
> : FOR  ${address}  in  @{addresslist}
> \   ${city} =  Get From Dictionary  ${address}   city
> \   ${key}=  set variable  ${address.keys()}
> \   ${listkey}=  get from list  ${key}  0
> # Since I know list 0 is city, but it's kind of hardcoded
> \   log to console  ${listkey}, ${city}
> ```
>
> #### Why is the first example failing, and how can I fix it?

Raw:

```
I am trying to display a JSON file as key value pairs.

Here is the JSON file:

    {"class": {"id": 0,"name": "David"},"alladdress": {"count": 3,"addresslist": [{"houseno": 1,"streetno": 5,"streetname": "tesla","city": "ABC","state": "AA","country": "UK","zip": 85555},{"houseno": 2,"streetno": 6,"streetname": "honda","city": "PQR","state": "BB","country": "IN", "zip": 5252}]}}

Here is the common code:

    Library  OperatingSystem
    Library  Collections
    ${json_data}=    Get file  detail.json
    ${data}=  evaluate  json.loads($json_data)  json
    ${alladdress}=  get from dictionary  ${data}  alladdress
    ${addresslist}=  get from dictionary  ${alladdress}  addresslist

In order to display the key value pairs, I wanted to use the following code to loop over the dictionaries under the list, but the code I tried below threw this error on the last line:

> @{address.keys()}' failed: Variable '${address}' not found.

    :FOR  ${address}  IN  @{addresslist}
    \  Loop over address  @{address}
    [Arguments]  @{address}
    :FOR  ${key}  IN  @{address.keys()}
    \  ${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${address}    ${key}
    \  log to console   ${key},${value}

However, this code works to display the key value pairs.

    : FOR  ${address}  in  @{addresslist}
    \   ${city} =  Get From Dictionary  ${address}   city
    \   ${key}=  set variable  ${address.keys()}
    \   ${listkey}=  get from list  ${key}  0
    # Since I know list 0 is city, but it's kind of hardcoded
    \   log to console  ${listkey}, ${city}

###Why is the first example failing, and how can I fix it?
```